# Exclude a specific query parameter from being logged in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I wonder if it's possible to exclude specific query parameters in the URI from being logged to the Nginx access log?

Here's our current configuration:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $host "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

Regardless of the request path, let's say I want the "latitude" parameter to be excluded from being logged (or preferably, it should be obfuscated). I know I can exclude *all* query parameters by changing "$request" to e.g. "$request_method $uri", but then I lose *all* parameters which is not what I want.

Update:

I want `GET /index.html?latitude=43.4321&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1` to be obfuscated to something like this: `GET /index.html?latitude=******&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GET /index.html?key=latitude&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1`
becomes
`GET /index.html?key=***&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1`

Here's the code:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $host "$customrequest" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
map $request $customrequest {
        ~^(.*)(latitude)(.*)$   "$1***$3";
        default                 $request;
}
```

You can add multiple keywords like this: `~^(.*)(latitude|dell|inspiron)(.*)$`

**Edit:**
After specification in the comment the regex needs to be modified:
`GET /index.html?latitude=5570&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1` becomes
`GET /index.html?latitude=***&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1`

```
map $request $customrequest {
        ~^(.*)([\?&]latitude=)([^&]*)(.*)$   "$1$2***$4";
        default                 $request;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to _value_ to be obfuscated for the specific key. I don't know the "value" of the key beforehand.

Comment: The more information you give in the beforehand the better are the answers.

Comment: I've asked a similar question for multiple parameters here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1046302/exclude-multiple-query-parameters-from-being-logged-in-nginx