# Exclude multiple query parameters from being logged in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

This question is similar to [Exclude a specific query parameter from being logged in Nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1046249/exclude-a-specific-query-parameter-from-being-logged-in-nginx/1046256) but for multiple parameters. What I want to do is to obfuscate *all* query parameters, that I specify, that are present in the request URI. For example, let's say that I have the following request:

```
GET /index.html?latitude=55.70&longitude=32.2341&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1
```

then I would like both `latitude` *and* `longitude` to be obfuscated in the logs:

```
GET /index.html?latitude=***&longitude=***&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1
```

If I try defining the log format like this:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $host "$customrequest" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

map $request $customrequest {
        ~^(.*)([\?&]latitude=|longitude=)([^&]*)(.*)$   "$1$2***$4";
        default                 $request;
}
```

then only the last parameter in the regex is taken into account and the result will be:

```
GET /index.html?latitude=55.70&longitude=***&otherkey=value HTTP/1.1
```

which is *not* what I want.

So the questing is, how can I configure Nginx to obfuscate *all* of the given (query/uri) parameters that I've defined?

I'm using Nginx 1.19.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cascade `map` statements. It may not be very efficient, but it is easily extended. Also, you will need to use named captures, as the numeric captures will be overwritten.

For example:

```
map $request $custom1 {
    ~^(?<prefix1>.*[\?&]latitude=)([^&]*)(?<suffix1>.*)$  "${prefix1}***$suffix1";
    default                                               $request;
}
map $custom1 $customrequest {
    ~^(?<prefix2>.*[\?&]longitude=)([^&]*)(?<suffix2>.*)$ "${prefix2}***$suffix2";
    default                                               $custom1;
}
```